# Bootstrap datepicker getDate and SQL

Tags: javascript, php, sql, twitter-bootstrap, getdate

i want to get date from and make SQL query with it, but i have a little problem :S
I cant get the date and i don't know how to give to an php variable :S
 Even more i'm not allowed to use submit (Post and Get methods)

```
 <?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
{
    $hi='';
}else
{
    header("location:login.php");
}
require_once '../../templates/DBconnect.php';
$link = DBconnect::connect();
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>bootstrap datepicker examples</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS and bootstrap datepicker CSS used for styling the demo pages-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/datepicker.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" width="50%">
            <div class="hero-unit" width="50%">
                <input  type="text" placeholder="Begin Date"  id="example1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" width="50%">
            <div class="hero-unit" width="50%">
                <input  type="text" placeholder="End Date"  id="example2" onchange="hole()">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Load jQuery and bootstrap datepicker scripts -->
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // When the document is ready


            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#example1').datepicker({
                    format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
                });  

            });
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#example2').datepicker({
                    format: "dd-mm-yyyy"
                });  

            });

        function hole(){
        this.$('.example1').datepicker('getDate');
        alert($('#example1').val());
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use AJAX then, it allows you to execute PHP without having to refresh your page. You would basically need to make a separate PHP file and send your date value to that file through AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use client side script such as JavaScript to pass the SQL query without submitting the page. Some JavaScript libraries such as jquery can be used with minimal JavaScript code.